# SHA256 and RIPEMD160 collisions

Tags: hash, elliptic-curves, sha-256, ripemd

`H = ripemd160(sha256(ECMultiply(A,G)))`

`A` - **32**-byte number,

`H` - **20**-byte number,

`G` - generator point,

`ECMultiply` - elliptic curve point multiplication.

Is it true that there is many `A` that have the same `H`?

Answer (score 9):

There are close to $2^{256}$ ECC keys while there are only $2^{160}$ 20-byte hashes, so the [pidgeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) shows that there exist collisions. On average there there are $2^{96}$ keys for each 20-byte hash.

Since SHA-256 is a strong hash function, the only way to find a collision is brute force, which involves $2^{80}$ hash computations. But collisions are not a relevant attack for bitcoin addresses, since stealing your own money is rather pointless.

What an attacker needs to do is a multi-target preimage attack, which is ridiculously more expensive than the expected rewards ($2^{160}$ hash computations to steal 67 billion USD, which means more than $2^{120}$ hash computations for each dollar you steal).

It's clearly better for the attacker to attack the address with a known ECC public key and the highest balance, since that costs $2^{128}$ operations, but reaps all bitcoins from that address.